# Is it possible to apply custom font for freemarker template

Tags: java, fonts, freemarker

I used **freemarker** templates (+  jsoap, org.xhtmlrenderer) to create a PDF file, and currently have to apply custom .ttf font during PDF generation.
I haven't found any information about custom fonts on the official website.
@font-face doesn't work

is it possible to use a custom font in freemarker?

Comment: I doubt you are only using FreeMarker to create the PDF.. aren't you using an additional library?

Comment: yeah, also jsoap, org.xhtmlrenderer

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7525403/how-to-embed-font-in-pdf-created-from-html-with-itext-and-flying-saucer

Answer (score 0):

[jasper-de-vries](https://stackoverflow.com/users/880619/jasper-de-vries) thanks, your comment helped to solve the problem
this link for doc with code example - http://flyingsaucerproject.github.io/flyingsaucer/r8/guide/users-guide-R8.html#xil_32

I have to add custom font into font resolver